# Scrapy Follow & Scrape next Pages

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having a problem where none of my scrapy spiders will crawl a website, just scrape one page and seize. I was under the impression that the `rules` member variable was responsible for this, but I can't get it to follow any links. I have been following the documentation from here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider

What could I be missing that is making none of my bots crawl?

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from Example.items import ExItem

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.ac.uk"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.example.ac.uk',
    )

    rules = ( Rule (LinkExtractor(allow=("", ),),
                    callback="parse_items",  follow= True),
    )
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Can you post the actual link to the website you are trying to crawl ?

Comment: No, no errors at all. the parse items function works line too.

Comment: Can you post the website link?

Comment: I just tried your code and it works fine for me. Can you post the log?

Comment: ...I don't think you understand. It works fine, it just won't go to the next page and start scraping. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: What i meant is it is going to the next pages for me and I do not see anything wrong with your code. What is the message on your spider stop signal?

Comment: It only scrapes page 1 for me: `2015-03-02 08:41:27+0000 [example] INFO: Closing spider (finished). 2015-03-02 08:41:27+0000 [example] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
 {...
  'finish_reason': 'finished',`

Comment: replace your rule with this one `rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('course-finder', ),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]',)), callback='parse_items',follow=True),
    )`

Comment: @Monodeep it lives! thank you so much for your help. Can you please submit your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your rule with this one :

```
rules = ( Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('course-finder', ),restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="pagination"]',)), callback='parse_items',follow=True), )
```