# Scrapy -- Scraping a page and scraping next pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape RateMyProfessors for professor statistics defined in my **items.py** file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define here the models for your scraped items
#
# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class ScraperItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    numOfPages = Field() # number of pages of professors (usually 476)

    firstMiddleName = Field() # first (and middle) name
    lastName = Field() # last name
    numOfRatings = Field() # number of ratings
    overallQuality = Field() # numerical rating
    averageGrade = Field() # letter grade
    profile = Field() # url of professor profile

    pass
```

Here is my **scraper_spider.py** file:

```
import scrapy

from scraper.items import ScraperItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class scraperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "scraper"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ratemyprofessors.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryBy=teacherName&schoolName=pennsylvania+state+university"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="nextLink"]')),callback='parse',follow=True),
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        # professors = []
        numOfPages = int(response.xpath('((//a[@class="step"])[last()])/text()').extract()[0])

        # create array of profile links
        profiles = response.xpath('//li[@class="listing PROFESSOR"]/a/@href').extract()

        # for each of those links
        for profile in profiles:
            # define item
            professor = ScraperItem();

            # add profile to professor
            professor["profile"] = profile

            # pass each page to the parse_profile() method
            request = scrapy.Request("http://www.ratemyprofessors.com"+profile,
                 callback=self.parse_profile)
            request.meta["professor"] = professor

            # add professor to array of professors
            yield request


    def parse_profile(self, response):
        professor = response.meta["professor"]

        if response.xpath('//*[@class="pfname"]'):
            # scrape each item from the link that was passed as an argument and add to current professor
            professor["firstMiddleName"] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="profname"]/span[@class="pfname"][1]/text()').extract() 

        if response.xpath('//*[@class="plname"]'):
            professor["lastName"] = response.xpath('//h1[@class="profname"]/span[@class="plname"]/text()').extract()

        if response.xpath('//*[@class="table-toggle rating-count active"]'):
            professor["numOfRatings"] = response.xpath('//div[@class="table-toggle rating-count active"]/text()').extract()

        if response.xpath('//*[@class="grade"]'):
            professor["overallQuality"] = response.xpath('//div[@class="breakdown-wrapper"]/div[@class="breakdown-header"][1]/div[@class="grade"]/text()').extract()

        if response.xpath('//*[@class="grade"]'):
            professor["averageGrade"] = response.xpath('//div[@class="breakdown-wrapper"]/div[@class="breakdown-header"][2]/div[@class="grade"]/text()').extract()

        return professor

# add string to rule.  linkextractor only gets "/showratings.." not "ratemyprofessors.com/showratings"
```

My issue lies in the **scraper_spider.py** file above.  The spider is supposed to go to [this](http://www.ratemyprofessors.com/search.jsp?queryBy=teacherName&schoolName=pennsylvania%20state%20university) RateMyProfessors page and go to each individual professor and grab the info, then go back to the directory and get the next professor's info.  After there are no more professors left on the page to scrape, it should find the *href value* of the **next button** and go to that page and follow the same method.

My scraper is able to scrape all the professors on page 1 of the directory, but it stops after because it won't go to the next page.

Can you help my scraper successfully find and go to the next page?

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805663/scrapy-follow-scrape-next-pages) StackOverflow question but it was too specific to be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem by ignoring rules all together and following the **Following links** section of [this doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 3):

Your `scraperSpider` should inherit from `CrawlSpider` if you want to use the `rules` attribute. See the docs [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider). Also be aware of this warning from the docs

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I apologize that this is a couple days late as I have been busy.  Would you recommend any other function to use?  I need to scrape the next page using the `parse()` method.  I imported `CrawlSpider` as you suggested, but it does not continue and scrape the next page, instead, it dumps the same professors from the first page 10 times into my JSON file.  Any advice?